# Why I am getting an "unsupported client" message when I try to connect to Salesforce using Perl's SOAP::Lite?

Tags: perl

> UNSUPPORTED_CLIENT: TLS 1.0 has been disabled in this organization. Please use TLS 1.1 or higher when connecting to Salesforce using https.

I am using the [`SOAP::Lite`](https://metacpan.org/pod/SOAP::Lite) module

Comment: You don't appear to have asked us a question. What are you trying to do? Where is your code?

Answer (score 4):

[SOAP::Lite](https://metacpan.org/pod/SOAP::Lite) is based on [LWP](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP). The https support in LWP is ultimately done by using the OpenSSL library. My guess is that you are using a very old OpenSSL library with no support for TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2, typically either OpenSSL 0.9.8 or OpenSSL 1.0.0 since support for TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2 was only added in OpenSSL 1.0.1. Such old OpenSSL libraries are typically installed on older systems but also on newer MacOS systems.

To fix the problem you need to upgrade both OpenSSL and the Perl-bindings for it ([Net::SSLeay](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SSLeay) on newer systems or [Crypt::SSLeay](https://www.nu42.com/2014/08/dont-declare-dependency-on-cryptssleay.html) on older, depending on your version of LWP).

Comment: I will note that because `Crypt::SSLeay` depends on `LWP::Protocol::https`, upgrading it will automatically upgrade `LWP` and install `IO::Socket::SSL` and `Net::SSLeay`, and, unless the programmer engages in self-sabotage by manually overriding the defaults, `LWP` is going to use the recommended `Net::SSLeay` bindings to OpenSSL.

Comment: I am using RHEL5 where openssl version is 0.9.8. I have added the version 1.0.1 on my path and build the perl again. But still getting the same error.

Crypt::SSLeay version is latest one 0.72 in my perl installation.

Comment: @npandey:I don't know what exactly you mean with "added the version ... on my path" but if it is just PATH then it is not sufficient. Also, you don't need to rebuild Perl but the Net::SSLeay module which is not part of Perl by default. See the README inside the Net::SSLeay distribution for a description on how to compile it with a specific openssl installation.

Comment: Many Thanks Steffen. It has been resolved after following your suggestions.
Many thanks again